# Pattern match in SQL Server using regular expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to identify these kind of patterns in a SQL Server (2019) column:

78878001

1-1321-32

1321-12

121-5489-19

403-3-XXXXX

The rules are:

- only numbers
  OR
- only numbers and hyphens (at least one hyphen one but no specific number of them)
  OR
  numbers, hyphens and letter X

I tried this:

```
    SELECT * FROM [TABLE1] WHERE [Part no] like  '[0-9]%-%'
```

But it returns some incorrect values like:

7. 702-3-01960 09150006125

700-3-02474  Arkds 4787-PA-51H-99999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using at least SQL Server 2012, I think you could solve this with try_parse. Using your data as an example:

```
create table #testing1 (val varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #testing1 
VALUES
('78878001'),
('1-1321-32'),
('1321-12'),
('702-3-01960 09150006125'),
('700-3-02474 Arkds 4787-PA-51H-99999'),
('121-5489-19'),
('403-3-XXXXX')

select * 
from #testing1
where try_parse(replace(replace(val, '-', ''), 'X', '') AS int) is not null
```

Comment: Excellent, will accept as answer, thank you very much for your quick help

Comment: @User123 Solid approach +1, however you may want to consider BIG INT vs INT.   Adding just two digits to 78878001 would exceed the max value of an integer and therefore return NULL and be excluded

Comment: Very good point, than you John, will adjust the function accordingly

Comment: `TRY_CAST` probably faster if culture is not involved

Comment: As I read the OP's requirements an `'X'` is only allowed if there is a hyphen present. How does your code implement that check? Perhaps @User123 would clarify the requirements since this is the (currently) accepted answer.